# Filling DropDownList using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC 4 error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in JQuery and AJAX. I tried to fill a DropDownList using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC 4 and it gives me this error:
**The ObjectContext instance has been deleted and can not be used for operations that require a connection.**
and here is my script:

```
function LoadFlights() {
var $flight = $('#IDFLIGHT');
$flight.empty();
$flight.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Please Wait...'));

$.ajax({
    url: '/Flight/GetFlightList',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (d) {
        $flight.empty();
        $flight.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Select Flight'));
        $.each(d, function (i, val) {
            $flight.append($('<option></option>').val(val.IDFLIGHT).html(val.DATEFLIGHT));
        });
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
}
```

And this is the action in the controller **Flight** I call:

```
public JsonResult GetFlightList()
    {
        FlightService flightService = new FlightService();
        var all = flightService.GetAll();
        return new JsonResult { Data = all, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };         
    }
```

The variable **all** has data but it still give me the error mentioned  above.
Thank you

Comment: So you are saying that ajax call comes to server to your action and return successfully from action?

Comment: No, didn't say that it return successfully from the action. But I said that the variable "all" has the value. the problem is in returning data as JSON I guess

Comment: replace ``$.each(d`` with ``$.each(d.Data``

Comment: it still give the same error !

Comment: Materialize your query - `var all = flightService.GetAll().ToList();` If that is not working, show your `GetAll()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return Json(all,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, just passing the list data to the constructor will not convert it to JSON object.

P.S. the funtion `Json()` will return `JsonResult`